# Is this Poison Hemlock?

Tags: species-identification, botany

There is a lot of this growing in standing water near a drainage route and spring. It looks similar to water or poison hemlock.

[image: picture of plant]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is most likely [water cress](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Watercress) (*Nasturtium officinale*), which is in the cabbage family ([Brassicaceae](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brassicaceae)).

This is a water dwelling species that has white flowers and leaves in a pinnately compound form and flowers in clusters.

In contrast, [hemlock](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conium_maculatum) (*Conium maculatum*) has its flowers in distinct [umbels](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Umbel) (umbrella shape), and the leaves are also pinnate, but deeply divided and lacy in appearance as opposed to the intact and [lightly toothed](https://www.treehugger.com/id-trees-using-leaf-shape-venation-1343511) edges on watercress.

Here's a picture of hemlock leaf from [Iowa State University](https://crops.extension.iastate.edu/encyclopedia/poison-hemlock), contrast it to the ones in your question:

[image: hemlock]

Comment: Thanks! It looked similar but is missing distinguishing features like umbels, 5 petals, reddish stem, protruding stamen, etc.

Comment: @noshery no problem, it is certainly good to get clarification around these sorts of things. Water cress is very edible and tasty, though rather peppery when raw - tastes like radish or mustard. If you are certain that the water source is clean (i.e. not polluted or have human/animal waste in it), then harvesting and eating is a possibility, but could need cooking if in doubt as to the water.